# Error building boost on Mountain lion using gcc-mp-4.7 installed from macports

Tags: boost, macports, gcc4.7, cpp-netlib

I've run into a very very hairy issue. My end goal is to build the cpp-netlib. cpp-netlib uses C++-11, it was throwing linker errors with original boost build in my machine. The reason I'd built boost using the default gcc installed in my machine, which works just fine. However, following the steps given in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html {section 5.2 onwards} does not seem to help me. I'm getting errors like this

```
..failed gcc.link.dll stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.dylib...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_thread.dylib for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.7      /release/threading-multi>libboost_system.dylib...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-4.7/release/threading-multi>libboost_chrono.dylib for 
lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.7/release/threading-multi>libboost_system.dylib...
..skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_timer.dylib for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-4.7/release/threading-multi>libboost_chrono.dylib...
gcc.link.dll bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.7/release/threading-multi/libboost_date_time.dylib
ld: unknown option: -h
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I added my dependency in the user-config.jam specifying the mac-ports gcc path and invoking b2 with toolset gcc-4.7. My end goal is an application which uses cpp-netlib to make http calls and I want to use boost regex as well in my app.